# Splitting html code into parts

Tags: html, tags, html-parsing

i'm volunteering for an organization and am helping them make an Android app where we download html from an atom feed to the app database for presentation inside the app. The html articles are entered in an online CMS system and presented on the website of the organization as well in a regular way

The thing is that when we get the html inside the app we would like to split it up for formatting and extracting different parts. I'm thinking that we are going to need to put custom invisible markers of some sort into the html. So my question: What is the best way to do this?

A few ideas i have come across:

- custom html tags
- `<span>` with a class/id attribute
- `<div>` with a class/id attribute
- putting the class/id attribute into existing tags (like `<h1>` etc)
- html inline comments

What do you think of these options? Are there better alternatives? Is there another way to think about this whole problem?

Grateful for help and with kind regards, Tord

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked with a web professional friend of mine and she voted for using `<div>` and `<span>` tags with the `id` attribute for describing the different sections. For inline content `<span>` is best, and for other (more high-level) cases we use `<div>`. These tags can then be used to split the text in our Android app using `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf`

Comment: There's also [this](http://htmldog.com/guides/html/intermediate/sectioning/) in html5, but it does not fit our content. May be of interest to others though

Answer (score 0):

Split the HTML code up into multiple files, then use a server side language to bring them all together for your index.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, unfortunately this won't work because we use a CMS for entering the text and want to keep it by article. Can i ask which of the ideas listed above is best (or least bad) in your opinion? I welcome any feedback!